# How can I unit test a MVC controller[normal controller and not a web api controller] using a web api for its data?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, unit-testing, mocking, asp.net-web-api

How can I test a normal controller that consumes a web api service (making a call to web api).

Also I want to mock the web api data in the controller action (consuming web api as a service) that I am testing.

Say I am testing `public actionresult Home()` and this method uses a web api GET to fetch data, I want to mock this api call? How can I achieve this?

Comment: Use repositories to retrieve data and mock the repository.

Comment: Based on your question, generally it is about stubbing out external services such WebAPI calls. If you have a specific code sample that you trying to test, I should be able to give you a more precise answer. Otherwise there should be plenty of examples on the SO. See also http://www.peterprovost.org/blog/2012/06/16/unit-testing-asp-dot-net-web-api/

Comment: @Jeroen Vannevel:I am using entity framework and repositories in my web api layer(which is external).So that means  I have create repositories in my web application as well and copy all the models to web application  as I have in my web api layer?

Comment: @Spock:your answer deals with just testing web api But my question is not to test the web api itself but to test a non-web api controller consuming web api.

Comment: @user1128681 As I can see you are a new user. The answer depends on few assumptions. It not clear you are using any async calls to retrieve WebAPI data, it is not clear you use any isolation frameworks? Based on these, the answer vary. As I mentioned in my comments, it is tough to give you a specific answer without seeing any code. I understand that you might have privacy issues that you might not want the code to publish in SO. If that;s the case you can at least provide some fake implementation similar to you actual code. The community would appreciate it.

Comment: @spock  my question is very simply described that I am testing public actionresult Home() and this Home action calls web api for its data and  and I want to mock the web api call.I think it cannot be described more simpler than this  and you are trying to assume too many things which I have not mentioned but you must try to focus on what I have mentioned like Jeroen Vannevel has focussed and answered correctly.The question is now closed and thanks for attempting to answer my question althought not correctly.

Comment: If your MVC controller has to call a Web Api to fetch data for purpose of testing - you do something wrong in there